# How to remove certain string of charactors in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

Let me start off be saying I am new to trasactsql and query so please be kind.
I have a DB with about 1700 records for my product file, and one field (name) has the product code, a space and then the name of my product. I have another field (pcode) with just the product code that has numbers and possibly a letter or two that matches the beginning of the "name" field. I need to remove all characters in front of the space in 'name" including the space. Is there a way to remove the characters if they match what is in "pcode"?

Here is an example.

**What I have;**

pcode | name

1234  |  1234 widget

---

**What I want;**

pcode | name

1234  |   widget

There are some names with spaces in them. ie. "Left Handle Button side" or "Control "Lever"

Thanks in advance.
Michael

Answer (score 1):

In a `select`, you can do:

```
select pcode, substring_index(name, ' ', -1)
. . .
```

In an `update`:

```
update table t
    set name = substring_index(name, ' ', -1)
    where name like '% %';
```

If you want to change the data in place (using an `update`), check the logic (or copy the table) before doing the update.  This might not do what you expect, for instance, if the name itself has a space in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to export it to MS Excel for example and do it manually. Next time learn about 12 gold rules when creating SQL database.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules